# M2 - Use price for calculation

Tags: magento2, price, calculate

On the product detail page I need to use the price for calculation. How can I get the price and use it for calculation?

For example; $product_price / 12 = $outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$product->getFinalPrice();
```

Where `$product` is the current product you are viewing.

Comment: Thanks, works great!